# Retrieve the key from multi dimension list if the value exists in first colum

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to retrieve the key of the value 1 if 1 exists in first column of a list.
For example:

```
{1: [3, 2, 3, 2],
2: [1, 2, 3, 4], 
3: [3, 4, 2, 1],}
```

We have 1 in located key 2 first column. How can I retrieve it? my brain froze in this step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
print([k for k in d if d[k][0] == 1  ])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a list comprehension -

```
[k for k,v in d.items() if v[0]==1]
```

```
[2]
```